# Error when installing webpack React and Redux npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, redux, npm-install

I am following the tutorial on React and Redux on thenewboston Youtube channel, and just can't install dependencies when I navigate to the directory where the files are provided. Here's the link, and I am following exactly the tips from the beginning of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSAw5f8mOQs&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBbSLZjvleMwldX8jGgXV6a&index=3

This is the error I get:

```
:~$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/joe/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-56-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/joe
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/joe/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/joe/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: You are missing the file package.json

Comment: well it's inside the folder(the folder I drag into the terminal in order to get path), do I need to put it somewhere else maybe?

Comment: Your current working directory is `/home/joe` and you do not have a `package.json` inside it. Can you show the result of `ls -l /home/joe/package.json`, `cat  /home/joe/package.json` and `cat <backtick here>pwd<backtick here>\package.json`

Comment: What is the folder where you put you package.json?

Comment: It says No such file or directory, sorry I'm new to this. json is in the folder with other files downloaded from the repo, should I change the working directory and copy it there? Could you please direct me how to do that if possible..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing package.json.

There are two possibilities:

#### You want to create new package.json

If you want to create a new package.json use `npm init` command to setup your package.json.

#### You already have some code with a package.json

If you already got some code from some repo,  `cd` to that directory where you have your `package.json` and do a `npm install` or `npm i`